# Splitting dynamically allocated array without linear time copy

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I am working with a list of array in C++, each in an object and wanted to split some of them.
These are allocated dynamically.

I wanted to do the split in constant time as it is theoretically possible:
 from

```
[ pointer, size1 ]
```

to

```
[ pointer, size2 ]; [ other array ]; [ pointer + size2, size1-size2 ]
(+ other data each time)
```

I tried to use `malloc` and simply create a new pointer incremented with the size.
As it could be expected, I got error due to the automatic freeing of the memory.

I tried a `realloc` starting at the second address, but as in "what is the difference between `malloc` and `calloc`" on this site already told me it is not possible.

Is there a way to avoid recopying the second part and define correctly the pointer? 
Having a linear cost where I know I can have constant time is frustrating.

```
    class TableA
    {
     public:
      (constructor)
      void divide(int size); // the one i am trying to implement
      (other, geteur, seteur)
     private
      Evenement* _el;
      vector<bool>** _old;//said arrays
      int _size;
    }
```

nothing really complicated

Comment: You need to put up some code, your description is not very clear...

Comment: Is this a C question or a C++ question.  If the latter, you probably shouldn't be using malloc'd arrays at all.

Comment: Please edit your comments into your question to make the question clearer.  All else apart, you can format the text in the question, unlike in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have only part of a dynamic array freed by keeping track of pointers and length. However, you can fake this by making a new class to manage the starting array, allocate it however you want and have it managed by a std::shared_ptr.

You simply return a Class containing a shared_ptr to memory, plain pointer to first element, and array size. When the current Array class goes out of scope, the shared_ptr gets decremented, and when no slices of the memory are used anymore, the memory gets freed.

You need to be careful with this though, as there may be multiple objects referencing the same memory, but there's ways around that (marking the original invalid after splitting with a bool for example).

[Edit] Below is a very basic implementation of this idea. A `split()` operator can very easily be implemented in terms of 2 `slice()` operations. I'm not sure how you want to implement this in terms of your example above, as I'm not sure how you manage your `vector<bool> **`, but if you wanted the possibility of splitting your `vector<bool>`, you could instantiate a `ShareVector<bool>`, or if you have an array of `vector<bool>`, your make a `SharedVector<vector<bool>>` instead.

```
#ifndef __SharedVector__
#define __SharedVector__

#include <memory>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
class SharedVector {

    std::shared_ptr<T> _data;
    T *_begin;
    size_t _size;
    // perhaps add size_t capacity if need for limited resizing arises.

public:
    SharedVector<T>(size_t const size)
    : _data(std::shared_ptr<T>(new T[size], []( T *p ) { delete[] p; })), _begin(_data.get()), _size(size)
    {}

    // standard copy and move constructors work fine

    // pass shared_ptr by reference to avoid unnecessary refcount changes
    SharedVector<T>(std::shared_ptr<T> &data, T *begin, size_t size)
    : _data(data), _begin(begin), _size(size)
    {}

    T& operator[] (const size_t nIndex) {
        assert(nIndex < _size);

        return _begin[nIndex];
    }  

    T const & operator[] (const size_t nIndex) const {
        assert(nIndex < _size);

        return _begin.get()[nIndex];
    }

    size_t size(){
        return _size;
    }

    SharedVector<T> slice(size_t const begin, size_t const end) {
        assert(begin + end < _size);

        return SharedVector<T>(_data, _begin + begin, end - begin);
    }

    T *begin() {
        return _begin;
    }

    T *end() {
        return _begin + _size;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I notice in your code the '_data(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int[size] ':

are you using int as the 1 octet object? would char work instead?

Comment: Ahh sorry, that's a mistake, it should of course be T, not int. Thanks for pointing it out. Note that this keeps any memory that you allocate around, it's just an access convenience. If you create an array of size 100, split it into 2 of 50, and delete one of those later, you still have 100 items allocated. But you don't have to worry about deleting the data later on as it gets deleted when the original and the other split part are destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the malloc library can't cope with mallocing a chunk of memory and then freeing it slices.

You can do what you want, but you must only free the memory all at once right at the end using the original pointer that malloc handed you.

e.g.

```
int* p = malloc(9 * sizeof(int));
int* q = p + 3;
int* r = p + 6;
// Now we have three pointers to three arrays of three integers.

// Do stuff with p, q, r

free(p); // p is the only pointer it is valid to free.
```

By the way, if this is really about C++, there are probably standard C++ data structures you can use.

Comment: Do you know how to prevent the other, invalid, free automatically used after the last use of the object?

Comment: @wolfgangdurand If the malloc'd memory is being shared amongst several objects, you'll have to implement some sort of mechanism so that it is not freed until the last object goes away.  Some sort of reference counting mechanism would work, but this really looks like a bad design.  Take a step back and think of a better way.

Comment: Yes it is (a bad design) 
But using the tools of c++ wouldn't allow a splitting either.
Do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: I don't program in C++ but I'n sure you are wrong about that.  Personally, I'd just take the hit of the copy unless profiling the code shows it to be a serious performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `malloc` and create new pointer idea is good. But you need to free the memory manually I think.

Comment: That was my first try, but i don't know how to prevent the free at the destructor of the object : i have had several glitch or segmentation fault related to this

Comment: Did you try to manually free the pointer which you use to allocate the original array? Not the one you use to indicate the start of the second array.

Comment: I am still using it.
I mean : i use both the new and previous pointer (with different size)
My issue is that the compiler want to free the first at some point.
But you gave me an idea.

Comment: OK so you want to have part of the array inside of a object can still work after you destroy the object?

Comment: This means i didnt understand what you meant.
please escuse my lack of comprehension.
Can you clarify ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the runtime want to call the destructor only when the life of one object is about to end, right? Do you want to access the array after the object has been destructed?

Comment: Normally not the part that was attributed to this object, but i may access the second half after the first object is deleted
Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I think you need to copy because the array will be freed with the object. And the behavior of using a pointer which points to a freed memory is undefined.

Comment: Do you know how to prevent that? (the freeing)

Comment: How about allocate the memory not in the object, the pointer inside of the object only points to an array allocated by a different object which you always keep.

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `std::copy`.

```
int* p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    p[i] = i;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    std::cout << p[i];

// tmp will hold 3 values
// p2 will hold 2 values
// so we want to copy first 3 into tmp
// and last 2 into p2
int tmp[3];
std::copy(p, p+3, tmp);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << tmp[i];
int p2[2];
std::copy(p+3, p+5, p2);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    std::cout << p2[i];
// get rid of original when done
free(p);
```

Output:

```
0123401234
```

Comment: memcopy, std::copy ... are linear copy, whose cost increase with the size. I whish to have a constant time operation, which is, i know, theoretically possible

Comment: @wolfgangdurand, it's only linear if your objects don't follow a standard layout (i.e. non POD.) If they do, then this effectively ends up being a copy of one chunk of memory to another, of course time will vary depending on size of said chunk of memory, but it's about as constant time as you can get..

Comment: I didnot know that,i searched on memcopy, but the complexity information is rarely given and the only one i found was linear.
Do you know how it is done?

How do they do a constant time copy?

Answer (score 0):

The question is relatively unclear

But according to your topic

**splitting dynamically allocated array without linear time copy**

i would suggest you to use **linked list** instead of an array, you don't need to copy anything (and therefore no need to free anything UNLESS you wanna delete one of the item), manipulating the pointers would be sufficient for splitting a linked list

Comment: I also want to use the direct adressing of the array, improving a solution originally based on lists. In fact, i know there will be comparatively very few splittting. Thanks for the suggestion nevertheless